# Use chown every time a script is executed

Tags: bash

I am running a bash script as a root user for all of my sftp users. This script creates some files and then move it to a destination folder (DestFolder) for each user. Now, I use chown at the end to fix permissions for the whole destination folder, if the DestFolder exists, with: `chown -R DestFolder`. The DestFolder not always exists and some times was created from root as well. But, Most of the cases in the folder there are files that already have correct permissions on it. Is there any way to make chown to not give permissions for files that already have correct permissions on it and make it a little faster?

Comment: Are you trying to leave the existing permissions and ownership unchanged, because they'd be different and you want to keep them as they are? Or are you just trying to make the operation faster? If you're just trying to make the operation faster, it may not be worth the effort.

Comment: I am trying to make the operation faster, but if it is not worth it (it is computational worst), I will leave it as is.